# How can evenescent coupling work if an evanescent field cannot transport energy?

Tags: optics, reflection, waveguide

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4O-1CJx4s4w) shows a simulation of evanescent coupling between a driven optical fiber and another that is not driven. I had never heard of evanescent fields so I looked it up on Wikipedia, where I found the following:

> The transmitted wave cannot, however, be a sinusoidal wave, since it would then transport energy away from the boundary, but since the incident and reflected waves have equal energy, this would violate conservation of energy.

But the simulation demonstrates that some energy is transferred into the non-driven fiber. How is this possible if the evanescent wave isn't allowed to transport energy? Of course the simulation could be wrong, but from the comments it sounds like optical fiber technicians use this phenomenon regularly to check if a fiber is transmitting.

I looked at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297422/evanescent-wave-coupling) but A) it mostly goes over my head and B) it doesn't have a conclusive answer due to the question being insufficiently specific.

Comment: do you understand how waves can propagate in a metal waveguide?

Comment: and why do you think the *evanescent* field has no energy?

Comment: I had an electrodynamics class in college so I have a basic understanding of waveguides, but I don't remember any of the specifics.

Wikipedia and other sources say the definition of an evanescent field is that it cannot *transport* energy. The quote I provided above states "the incident and reflected waves have equal energy, [so the evanescent field transporting energy] would violate conservation of energy".

Comment: "having no energy" and "not being able to transport energy" are quite different things. I suggest that you open your old EM book and review how modes above a certain so called cut-off frequency *can* propagate in a waveguide and below that frequency (evanescent) it *cannot*, the former *carries* energy the latter *stores* energy. Then come back with your question.

Comment: It's been too long and I've forgotten too much. I'd have to retake electrodynamics to actually understand what's happening in the simulation. Hence why I came to a Q&A site and asked a question...

Comment: "modes above a certain so called cut-off frequency can propagate in a waveguide and below that frequency (evanescent) it cannot, the former carries energy the latter stores energy."

The simulation clearly shows an EM oscillation propagating through the non-driven fiber, which seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: what part of  the simulation "seems to contradict" my comment above. Think of two LC identical parallel resonators . Can you imagine that if one has been oscillating and you connect it to the other via a small capacitor $C_x$ so that $1/(\omega C_x) \gg\sqrt{L/C}$ then the other resonator will slowly be charged with energy and oscillates for a while and that "leaked" energy from the first resonator to the other can be captured by some circuitry?